# Joined SQL query MAX aggregate with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having trouble with a SQL query. Here is a representation of my schema on SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/14c8e/1

The issue is that I want to return rows of data from  the Invitations table and join them with a sum of both the 'sent' event_type and 'viewed' event_type from the associated events, as well as the latest created_at date.

I can get all the data and counts working, but am having issue with the last_sent_on. Is there a way I can use a condition in a MAX aggregate function?
e.g.

```
MAX(
  SELECT events.created_at
  WHERE event_type='sent'
)
```

If not, how would I write the proper subselect?

I am currently using Postgresql.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a case statement inside of max just as you've done with sum. The query below will select the maximum `created_at` for `event_type='sent'`

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    i.name,
    i.email,
    max(case when e.event_type='sent' then e.created_at end) AS last_sent_on,
    sum(case when e.event_type='sent' then 1 else 0 end) AS sent_count,
    sum(case when e.event_type='viewed' then 1 else 0 end) AS view_count
FROM
    invitations i
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    events e
    ON e.eventable_id = i.id
WHERE e.eventable_type='Invitation'
GROUP BY i.id, i.name, i.email
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/14c8e/4)

Comment: I don't know why I thought putting a case statement in the max aggregate wouldn't work... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery to build the max value for sent.

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    i.name,
    i.email,
    sent.last_sent,
    sum(case when e.event_type='sent' then 1 else 0 end) AS sent_count,
    sum(case when e.event_type='viewed' then 1 else 0 end) AS view_count
FROM
    invitations i
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    events e
    ON e.eventable_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT eventable_id uid, MAX(created_at) AS last_sent
            FROM events 
            WHERE event_type = 'sent'
            GROUP BY eventable_id ) AS sent
  ON sent.uid = i.id
WHERE e.eventable_type='Invitation'
GROUP BY i.id, i.name, i.email, sent.last_sent
```

Comment: Thank you! I prefer the case statement way listed above however.